# How can I write vcard to a file

Tags: node.js, npm, vcf-vcard

I tried to create a vcard via an API call. The following code shows,

```
var vcard = require('vcard-generator');
const vcardContent = vcard({
        name: {
            givenName: 'test',
            middleName: '',
            prefix: '',
            suffix: '',
        },
        formattedNames: [{
            text: '',
        }],
        nicknames: [{
            text: '',
        }],
        works: [{
            organization: 'AMT'
        }],
        emails: [{
            type: 'work',
            text: 'test@test.com',
        }],
        phones: [{
            type: 'sms',
            text: '+14035551515',
        }, {
            uri: 'sms://+14035551515',
        }],
        urls: [{
            type: 'test1',
            uri: 'https://test1.com',
        }, {
            type: 'test2',
            uri: 'https://test2.com',
        }],
    });

    console.log(vcardContent)
```

How can I write the above data as test.vcf file or any other npm available for handling vcard generation. And also I need to get the generated vcard via scaning QR code.

Comment: Bummer that no one was able to help. Including a more complete example, like your imports and development environment, may help others assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) package will allow you to write to the file system.

#### Writing to File System

```
var fs = require('fs');
var vcard = require('vcard-generator');
const vcardContent = vcard(
  {
    name: {
      givenName: 'test',
      middleName: '',
      prefix: '',
      suffix: '',
    },
    formattedNames: [{
      text: '',
    }],
    nicknames: [{
      text: '',
    }],
    works: [{
      organization: 'AMT'
    }],
    emails: [{
      type: 'work',
      text: 'test@test.com',
    }],
    phones: [
      {
        type: 'sms',
        text: '+14035551515',
      }, 
      {
        uri: 'sms://+14035551515',
      }
    ],
    urls: [{
      type: 'test1',
      uri: 'https://test1.com',
    }, {
      type: 'test2',
      uri: 'https://test2.com',
    }],
});
fs.writeFile("/path/to/save/to", vardContent, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Your vCard was saved!");
});
```

Comment: when using this npm , it shows  vcard is not a function while running the code. Was suceessfilly installed the node modules but its not properly working.

Comment: Try running `npm install --save vcard-generator`

Comment: Issue still exists... The command was already tried but shows vcard is not a function.

Comment: Be sure you are including `import vcard from 'vcard-generator';` at the header of your JavaScript file containing this method call.

Comment: As per the documentation `import vcard from 'vcard-generator'` import command is not recognized. So I am tried `var vcard = require('vcard-generator');` statement. I am using Node version 6.9.4.

Comment: chaged the node version and now vcard is generated. But it is not suppottig in my phone. The version of the vcard is 4.0.